# How to relate Flutter to Symfony6

Tags: flutter, authentication, symfony, jwt

I create database and user entity in my symfony project, I try it with postman (create user, get all users) and it work correctly
and I developed my Flutter interface to signup and signin.
My problem is how to relate my flutter to symfony

I tried this:

```
Future<void> _signup(BuildContext context) async {
    final String url = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/userCreate'; 
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'name': nameController.text,
      'email': emailController.text,
      'password': passwordController.text,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumberController.text,
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: jsonEncode(data),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    );

    final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (responseData['status'] == true) {
      // Signup successful, navigate to login screen or perform other actions
    } else {
      // Signup failed, display error message to the user
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(responseData['message'])),
      );
    }
  }
```

It works when I run it in windows or with navigator
but with my phone or emulator it give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of erros do you have ?

Have you set internet permission on android and/or iOs ?

In case you are using android emulator try to change 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2

In case it error due to internet permission, add following line

for iOs : Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

For Android : AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: this is the error i get 

Exception has occurred.
_ClientSocketException (ClientException with SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 48458, uri=https://127.0.0.1:8000/userCreate)


and this correct it " change 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.2"

Thank you

Comment: Happy it helped you. Don't forget to mark my answer as answered